# R - count total number of rows in every 15 minutes for each day

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
date  
2014-06-18 03:44:29   
2014-06-18 03:54:23  
2014-06-18 03:50:56   
2014-06-18 03:49:46   
2014-06-19 01:01:10   
2014-06-19 00:56:53   
2014-06-19 00:57:26   
2014-06-19 00:53:47   
2014-06-19 01:44:59   
2014-06-19 01:48:55  
2014-06-19 01:45:16
```

Its a data frame with thousand of rows. I need to count total no of rows in every 15 minute for each day. I need something like this:

```
date                                            count
2014-06-18 03:00:00 - 2014-06-18 03:15:00        2  
2014-06-18 03:15:00 - 2014-06-18 03:30:00        5  
2014-06-19 01:45:00 - 2014-06-19 02:00:00        15  
2014-06-19 02:00:00 - 2014-06-19 02:15:00        5
```

Is there any way to do this easily in R? Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure your values are properly formatted as POSIX date/time values.

```
dd <- c("2014-06-18 03:44:29", "2014-06-18 03:54:23", "2014-06-18 03:50:56", 
"2014-06-18 03:49:46", "2014-06-19 01:01:10", "2014-06-19 00:56:53", 
"2014-06-19 00:57:26", "2014-06-19 00:53:47", "2014-06-19 01:44:59", 
"2014-06-19 01:48:55")
dt <- strptime(dd, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Then, since POSIX date/times are stored as the number of seconds since 1970-01-01, you can round to the nearest 15 min interval with

```
round15 <- dt-(as.numeric(dt) %% (60*15))
```

And then round the occurrences with

```
table(round15)
```